# AWS timestream-write gets "An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) when calling the DescribeEndpoints operation: This operation is not allowed."

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-timestream

I am experimenting the AWS SDK for python to access Timestream. I tried their in house example code from the [repository](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-timestream-tools/tree/master/sample_apps/python) and I wrote my own code to create a database:

```
import boto3
from botocore.config import Config

client = boto3.client('timestream-write')

response = client.create_database(DatabaseName='test')
```

Both sample code and my own code got the following error:

> AccessDeniedException: An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) when
> calling the DescribeEndpoints operation: This operation is not
> allowed.

I googled a bit, but I could not find any information about it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Timestream is currently only available in a handful of regions. Make sure the boto3 region configuration set the correct region to those eligible ones.

Answer (score 1):

in your iam role add this permission policy

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "timestream:DescribeEndpoints"
        ],
        "Resource": "*"
    }
] }
```

DescribeEndpoints is called bt sdk in case you defined endpoints interface like this in your vpc
query-cell2.timestream..amazonaws.com.

Answer (score 0):

The credentials that you are using to interact with Timestream should use an IAM role that has has either an AWS managed policy or a custom policy that allow you to call timestream:DescribeEndpoints. See this page for an example: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/timestream/latest/developerguide/security_iam_id-based-policy-examples.html

Assuming you configured your environment to use the AWS CLI and ran `aws configure`, the IAM User that is tied to those credentials should be granted timestream:DescribeEndpoints. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-quickstart.html

You may have gotten this permissions error because you are missing TableName, which is a required parameter.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/timestream/latest/developerguide/API_CreateTable.html